# jquery Checking to see if element has element

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery 1.3 and is trying to duplicate the 1.4 .has functionality.

I need to check if the .page element contains the image, and if it doesn't, append it.

Is it something like:

```
var imageid = thirdimage;

if ($('#page:has(#'+imageid+')') === undefined) {
   $('#page').append($('#'+imageid));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: the has() selector has been available since 1.1.4 according to the doc. And I've used it specifically in 1.3.2.  Are you sure this isn't some other issue?  Maybe try `$('#page').find('#'+imageid) === undefined`

Comment: There's a new .has() method in 1.4

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
if( $('#page').find('#'+imageid).length )
  // I has the image! :P
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#page').find('#'+imageid).length == 0
```